# How can I split up a large model into an octree codewise?

Tags: opengl, java, collision-detection, lwjgl, octree

For collision detection, I am attempting to split up a large model into an octree.

If we take this black thing thing to be the ship (104,000 vertices):

[image]

Then I would like to split up the faces

[image]

I could easily split them up, but the problem is one of location. For example, if we take the bottom left chunk, how can I know that the projectile (in this case, a cannonball) is at that specific chunk?

And also how can I define the areas of the chunks in the first place? And for that matter, I need them to rotate with the ship as well!

I'm hopelessly lost as of how to do this, and so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Comment: Did you search for Octree construction algorithm ?

Comment: @concept3d I have, but I can't find any of them that do everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

first you transform the cannon ball into the coordinate space of the ship.

Then you act as *if you want to add the ball's model* to the octree and step down through the nodes. If the ball straddles a boundary line then go through both sides.

Once you get into a leaf not then there is the bucket with faces to test with.